# Algorithm to check common user between multiple properties

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have multiple properties in my domain and want to find users which are coming on all or more than one property.

You can the use case is like this:

```
property 1: {User A,User B,User C,User D }
property 2: {User A,User B,}
property 3: {User A,User B,User C}
```

So result would be like this:

> Property 1,2,3 has 50% same users
>   Property 1,2 has 50% same users
>   Property 2,3 has 50% same users
>   Property 1,3 has 75% same users

The issue here is that Users are in millions (over 20 million).
I can not use standard approach to use any list method as size would be pretty high.

Could you help me to find a good algorithm for this use case which is fast enough to hold this kind of data.

Comment: What is max count of properties?

Answer (score 0):

Use a bitmap of properties for each user. We have 3 properties here, so we need a bitmap of size 3 bits for each user

```
BITMAP : ABC => A = 0 or 1, B=0 or 1, C=0 or 1. 

User 1 -> 111
User 2 -> 111
User 3 -> 101
User 4 -> 100
```

Now for any query, write the query as a Bitmap and find which users include that bitmap.

For example,
    query: property 1, 2
    bitmap -> 110

```
Only user 1,2 include this bitmap.
Ans = 2/4 = 50%.
```

If the number of properties are not large(<64 or <128), you might use integers etc for faster computation.